# preg match on image

Tags: php, preg-match

I was wondering, I have this project in which a person copies a link into a form. Now this link has to be a image and what most of use guys say is never trust a user input.

I narrowed it down to preg_match() that can check that there is a image on the link which can be displayed on my site.

My question is basically how do you make sure that when checking the form, it is a image and not like a virus with a .jpg at the end of extension.

Comment: As long as you just put it in an `<img>` tag, it won’t be interpreted as executable and so a virus isn’t a concern. (Exploits notwithstanding.) (But if you do allow images on remote servers, be aware that they could track your users and such.)

Comment: You’re 14 and in university? Congratulations, by the way :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://foo.bar.com/path.jpg?arg=value#anchor';
if (preg_match("/\.(jpg|png)$/",parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH)){
    // YOUR CODE HERE
}
```

This matches a filename that ends with .jpg or .png.... just add in the parentheses the extensions you want to allow (separated by the | symbol)

Answer (score 0):

Use [finfo_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) to get the mime type of the file.

If the mime type is something like `image/gif` or  `image/png` ... then the file is an image.